# How do I get the proper SQLite assemblies for a project configured for x86 CPU?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sqlite

Background:

Working in C# using the 2.0 framework and setting up an application to use sqlite.  When deployed to certain customer machines I get:

```
Could not load file or assembly System.Data.SQLite.dll
```

I am under the impression that there should be no client install of SQLite as long as you've placed the above DLL in the runtime directory.  I have tried multiple configurations (x86 DLL compiled into a project targeting x86 cpu - failed on both x86 machines and x64 machines | x64 DLL compiled into a project targeting x64 CPU - failed on both x86 machines and x64 machines | both architecture versions of the DLL targeting Any CPU - failed on both x64 and x86).

I am using SQLite version 1.0.98.0.  I'm not sure what relevant code I could post as this is an issue with a DLL reference, but I am happy to upload anything needed to foster a reasonable answer.  I have no client computer cpu in mind so if I could get this running as x86 targeting x86 CPU that would be great.  Any yes, I have already tried that combination using the correct DLL while making sure it ends up in the runtime folder and it still fails.  If I could post more than two screen caps I would show the file as well, but alas I cannot.

I have been searching for quite a while and cannot seem to find an example that exactly fits what I want to do.  The question has been asked but not solved.  I read that the configuration of the DLL is what causes this and that is why I tried both DLL's targeting both processors.  Seeing that this question is asked a lot and I still couldn't find my answer I have to assume a lot of people are in the same position as me so maybe we can work this one out together and give the community a great post on solving this issue.

[Assembly information for the x86 configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeiN4.png)

[Configuration Manager for x86 CPU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6lPs.png)

Comment: This is a windows forms application, FYI.

Comment: can you post a picture of your project properties including the .net framework target version ?

Comment: @VinnyGuitara try just simple copying whole bin/debug(release) folder on client pc and try to run application. if it runs then there should be issue in the way setup is created. i had similar issue some days ago.

Comment: [Project Properties](http://imgur.com/xl5NaZ1)
Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: @Arjun Vachhani I already tried that... I've been taking the bin/debug folder to the client and it fails with the above error.  What did you do to resolve it other than taking bin/debug to the client?  Whats the actual fix within the application?

Comment: @VinnyGuitara  file not found exception is generally thrown when dll is not found at specific location. in my case bin/debug(release) folder had two other folders amd64 and x86(i was using sql server compact), but when installing it through setup it had all the files in same folder. so after modifying setup at what location files are installed i got application running perfectly

Comment: @Arjun If I set the project up to work just with x86 (which is fine with me) I have this as my path:
C:\SQLite\SQLLite\SQLLite\bin\x86\Debug
There is no other folders under this one... so this is where my System.Data.Sqlite.dll lives.  I thought this was the correct place for the file.  Do I need to create subfolders?

Comment: @VinnyGuitara it should be yourSolution\YourProject\Bin\Debug\x86

Comment: you have used nuget package manger to add sqlite, right ?

Comment: No... I downloaded [x86 Mixed Mode executable](http://imgur.com/iFSBg0U) directly from the sqlite website.  I believe my company blocks nuget:
[Nuget Error](http://imgur.com/kfm09vr)... That's entirely another issue though.

Comment: So we don't have a long chat on here Ill ask a targeted question... would the fact that my project is setup mySolution\myProject\Bin\x86 for debug be a problem?  Should I change the compiler output directories?

Comment: have you tried setting it to use `AnyCpu` also make sure that you are using the correct `.net 2.0` assembly for SqLite can the project be promoted to use `.net 4.x`

Comment: I have tried using AnyCPU and it works on most machines but the ones that fail are still failing even set at AnyCPU.  I am using the correct 2.0 sqlite assembly and I really don't want to target 4.x as this is being designed for some very old machines and its likely they have .net 1-2.... I don't want the user to be forced to do an install to use my application.

Comment: change your project output directory to bin\Debug\

Comment: @Arjun - I just changed the output directory.  I suppose that in and of itself is not going to fix the problem but its done:
[Output Directory Structure](http://imgur.com/768NLXD)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your dll are deployed properly on target machine. Some time setup compiler (Inno Setup) puts all the files in directory structure in same root folder hence .net can not file dll for expected path and hence it throws file not found exception

Comment: This sounds reasonable but maybe because I am a noob with SQLite I don't really know how the directory structure is supposed to look.  My System.Data.Sqlite.dll file is in the same folder as the executable. bin\debug.  If there is another place this dll should be so .net can find it where would that be?

Comment: I am not using INNO Setup - at this point I am just grabbing the output directory and moving it to the client machine to test.  So the application extension dll's are in the same folder as the .exe.... Isn't this how it should be setup?

Comment: after deployment  files-folder structure should be same as debug/release folder structure

Comment: Where do your executables live - one level up in the debug folder?  The dlls live in the folder down x86 | x64?  If thats the case then I should get everything writing to their respective folders and report back the results.  But is that the setup ideally?  bin\Debug for the application itself and bin\Debug\x86 for my dll?

Comment: executables are in debug/release folder

Comment: So maybe this is my root issue... the project is setup incorrectly.  When I hit build solution all of my exe's and dll's end up in the debug folder.  Where do I set this up?  In Configuration Manager?

Comment: see this screen shot and figure out http://imgur.com/a/GtTbZ how it should be, should always use nuget.

Comment: I'm thoroughly confused.  I tried to setup my folder structure like yours and its broken on everyones machine now.  I moved the dlls to x86 folder under debug and set my compiler output to the debug directory... The files were built correctly but now its broken client machines it was working on in the past.  I don't want this to be hopeless so there has to be something I did to my applications configuration that is causing this.

[Current Folder Structure](http://imgur.com/nwZMNRj)

Comment: The above screen shot was the wrong one... This is my [folder struct](http://imgur.com/CjeF4vB)

Comment: Here is a snap of my registry showing I do have the correct CLR and service pack:
[.Net Info from registry](http://i.imgur.com/Ph9p7s3.jpg)

Comment: I marked this as the answer because technically it was correct.  Once I got nuget functioning correctly and installed SQLite from there, it placed the correct DLL's where they needed to be.  I now have a functioning application for both x86 and x64 which is even better than what I wanted to begin with.